# write python black reformat on vim buffer :!black % and :e working in one step

Tags: python, vim

I want (**without any vim plugging**) run `black` on my vim buffer in one step.

So editing some Python code in vim.

I only get to have it working in two steps:

step 1:

```
:!black %
```

step 2 (to reload the buffer):

```
:e
```

Note this is not working:

```
:!black % |e
```

Comment: You can also use `set autoread` to automatically reload the file, which should do what you want.

Comment: Hint from the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:bar): `:execute '!black %' | e`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, we would follow this workflow:

1. Figure out how to use our code formatter in our shell as a filter.
2. Figure out how to use that filter from within Vim.
3. Make `:help gq` use that filter.

For all those steps, having [the formatter's doc](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage_and_configuration/the_basics.html) opened in a browser window is necessary.

### Step 1, figure out how to use our code formatter in our shell as a filter

Black can work with standard input:

```
$ black - < filename
[...]
reformatted -

All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.
```

But can we make it shut up?

```
$ black -q - < filename
[...]
```

Even in case of internal errors?

```
$ black -q 2>/dev/null - < filename
[...]
```

### Step 2, figure out how to use that filter from within Vim

From `:help filter`, we get:

```
!<motion>
:[range]!black -q 2>/dev/null -<CR>
```

which works a treat but that's a lot to type. It would be cool if Vim had a formatting command…

### Step 3, make `gq` use that filter

And indeed, Vim does have a formatting command: `gq`. `:help gq` points us to `:help 'formatprg'`, from which (and the linked sections) we can piece out the following (note the escaped spaces):

```
set formatprg=black\ -q\ 2>/dev/null\ -
```

Taking another look at the formatter's doc, it seems like providing a filename, even if we use standard input, might be a good idea:

```
set formatprg=black\ -q\ 2>/dev/null\ --stdin-filename\ %\ -
```

Finally, as it is only useful for Python files, let's add it to a custom Python filetype plugin:

```
" in after/ftplugin/python.vim
set formatprg=black\ -q\ 2>/dev/null\ --stdin-filename\ %\ -
```

At this point, we can use the built-in `gq<motion>` (part of the buffer) or `gggqG` (whole buffer) in a Python buffer without inventing new mappings or commands to memorize.

---

From there, you might want your buffer to be automatically formatted on write, for example, which will require reading up on `:help autocommands` and doing a bit of work on your side before you ask for help.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest one is

```
:%!black - -q
```

Comment: fantastic !, what does mean the `- -q` part ?

Comment: @user3313834 The tool must be set up to read from stdin and write to stdout.

Comment: this jumps the cursor back to the top of the buffer afterwards. how to prevent that?

Comment: This command differs from `!black %`, `!black %` requires new changes in a file to run (you have to first write `:w` and then use `!black %`-it will format and write formatted code again, otherwise you will get `No writes since last change`).   
This one-`%!black - -q` doesn't require any new writes but it will also not write after applying formatting, so you have to use it in this order `%!black - -q`, `:w`.